# Create tabs dynamically and add QTextbrowser to them: First tab is missing the QTextbrowser

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qtextbrowser

The code below creates a number of tabs (from "howmuchtab"s value) in a QTabWidget when clicking pushbutton. Each tab contains a QTextBrowser.

I want to refresh the tabs each time the PushButton is clicked.

Problem is: when clicking "Create Tabs" for the second time (and subsequents...), the QTextBrowser is not created into the first tab (others tabs are ok).

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Create Tabs', self)
        self.button.move(100, 70)
        self.report_window = ReportWindow()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.analyze_clicked)

    def analyze_clicked(self):
        self.report_window.fill_reports()
        self.report_window.show()


class ReportWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ReportWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tab)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def fill_reports(self):
        howmuchtabs = 5
        if self.tab.count() != 0:
            self.tab.clear()
        for i in range(howmuchtabs):
            self.create_tabs(self.tab, i + 1)
            self.tb.append(f"Textbrowser in Tab #{i + 1}")

    def create_tabs(self, obj, num):
        tabtoadd = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        obj.addTab(tabtoadd, str(num))
        self.tb = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(tabtoadd)
        self.tb.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.tb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 150, 30))
        self.tb.setObjectName(str(num))


def main():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pictures:

First click

[image]

Second click, QTextBrowser is not created into first tab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

self.tb what does QTextBrowser refer to? that is, when creating n tabs there will be n QTextBrowser, which of them is self.tb? Well, who knows (only the last one) so to avoid that kind of problem you just have to create a class that has that attribute:

```py
class PageWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, num, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.tb = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.tb.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.tb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 150, 30))
        self.tb.setObjectName(str(num))


class ReportWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ReportWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tab)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def fill_reports(self):
        howmuchtabs = 5
        if self.tab.count() != 0:
            self.tab.clear()
        for i in range(howmuchtabs):
            tabtoadd = self.create_tabs(self.tab, i + 1)
            tabtoadd.tb.append(f"Textbrowser in Tab #{i + 1}")

    def create_tabs(self, obj, num):
        tabtoadd = PageWidget(num)
        obj.addTab(tabtoadd, str(num))
        return tabtoadd
```

Comment: Thank you Eyllanesc. I'm a rookie and learned Python 1 month ago... this explains lots of things to me.